# Responsive images using wagtail image tag

Tags: html, css

I want an image to sit in a div which is 50% screen width ( with max width 800px for image in div) until 640px screen width where the div is 100%. I want the image to change height and width with the div. I want the whole image to always be shown. At the minute neither is changing and its messing up the responsiveness of the whole page. Everything is being pushed to the right.

```
<tr class="fadeInBlock">
  <td>
    <!--div for image of architecture-->
    <div class="homeInfo5">
      {{ page.architecturalText|richtext }}
    </div>


  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="homeIm4">
      {% for item in page.gallery_images.all %} {% image item.image width-500 class="responsive"%}
      <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
.homeIm4 {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}


@media all and (max-width:640px) {
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

In the image tag I have tried min max width original and fill. Nothing I've tried has worked. Without the image the responsiveness of the page is fine with just the text field.

I know about this link but it hasnt helped.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

Comment: Have you looked into using `background-image` or `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?

Comment: Is oject fit instead of the css in the responsiveness html?

Comment: This isn't really a Django/Wagtail question (all Wagtail is doing here is generating the HTML), so you might get a better response here if you rewrite your example code as plain HTML - that way, people who are unfamiliar with Django/Wagtail will be able to help too.

Comment: It is though because of the `{% image item.image width-500 class="responsive"%}`

Comment: @gasman Ive changed it so if i get people ripping me its your fault lol

Comment: @gasman changing it was huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `img{max-width:100%;}` using a parent `div`

Comment: Okay so I found you have to have height: auto; in the img tag aswell